# Using static function in class where a variable depends on constructor

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a class with a static function. This function is called as static by another part of the code, without instantiating a class object. However, this static function also has in its code a dependance on variable x. x, however, is only initialized to a certain value or cleared in the constructor. But, given that no object of the class is instantiated, I believe that the variable is undefined. So, I have a few questions:

1) Is the constructor called at all?

2) Is the variable x undefined?

How can I work around a case like that?

In the example below, i'd want y to be 25, but can it ever be?

```
class CExample
{
public:

    CExample(void);
    ~CExample(void);
    static void foo();

    int x;
};

CExample::CExample()
{
    x = 5;
}


void CExample::foo()
{
    int y = x*5;

}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bad design decision.  You should change your design so that there will always be something stored in `x` when you call the static function.

Comment: That won't compile, `x` needs to be static too (and needs a definition).

Comment: I understand it is, but I am wondering about the many static functions out there, do they always have to be completely self contained?

Comment: If you need to do stuff with instance members then pass an instance reference into the function

Comment: you're right, it doesn't compile saying the member is not static. In that case, declaring the member to be static would have set it to 0 correct?

Comment: It's set to whatever you set it to in your cpp file. You **declare** static members in the .h file and **define** them in your cpp file (hence initialize them with values there).

Comment: @gustafr: And if you don't explicitly set it to anything in your cpp file, then its set to 0

Comment: If you had two instances of the object CExample, one where x equaled 5 and another where x equaled 10, what would you expect the static call to foo result for y?  25? 50? 37.5? thrown an exception?  You need to understand the object instance model, and how static methods work within that framework.  Hopefully, my question will get you thinking about the difference between static methods, instance methods, and external functions, why/when to use each kind.

Comment: Thank you. I've changed my approach to this given all this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static member function is a service of the class, not of a specific object of the class. A class's static data members and static member functions exist independently of instantiation of a object of that class.

The use of a static function will not call the constructor of its respective class, therefore your variable will not exist, causing a compilation error.

Just remember static member functions exist and operate independently of any objects of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't compile since the static function is using a variable which will only exist in objects instantiated by the class.

I'm not sure you've understood static. Only **one** static function exist. You can call it from anywhere. Which instance if CExample's x is it supposed to use?

Comment: So you're meaning to say that the function exists, but the class doesn't and no other parts of the class can be accessed?

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky only static members can be accessed within static functions.  A static function has no knowledge of instance-level methods or members, since it operates on the class, not an instance

Comment: @DanF: I declared x static but it still complains that that foo is trying to access it.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky probably because you haven't **defined** it in your cpp file as: `int CExample::int = 0;` or something like that.

Comment: Defined it in the cpp class separately from the other members? Does it need to be declared inside of the function or outside? does it maintain its value between calls to the same function?

Comment: You should really read some tutorial on C++ programming Gustavo. This is not the place to learn the most fundamental parts of the language, I'm sorry. Anyway, I'll answer with a food for thought: It is a variable. It is static, so **it will reside in a specific memory location in your process** until your program ends. Will it maintain its value? Well, what do you think? :) You know, you're always allowed to write code which checks this, as a way of learning. Good luck, and have fun with C++!

Comment: @gustafr: I've been using C++ for many years without static functions and never had an issue until now that I was trying to take advantage of them. It might be an important part, but not always needed. This is the place to learn the language. It's a forum for asking questions, and you are more than welcome not to answer. Plenty of other questions are much more simpler than mine, such as "why does my code not compile" where the function doesn't have the right prototype. That is a basic question, yet in those cases I don't see downvoting and people complaining.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky, this is profound to all OO languages. You haven't really been **programming** C++ for years if this is still not clear to you, and that's why people downvote it. I'm sorry, and I hope you don't take this the wrong way. Again, tutorials will help you with this. So will books.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I need to brush up on this.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a case of bad design. You could fix it so that it compiles by making x static and initialising it with 5. However you are probably a lot of better rethinking your design and what you want it to do. Remember there is only ever one instance of something that is static but there are as many instances of CExample as times you call it's constructor.

Comment: Thanks. I did. I was simply trying to understand how to take advantage of static functions, but it's not as simple as I thought and as always requires careful design.

Answer (score 0):

It's illegal to access a non-static member from a static function. See the output of gcc when I try to compile your program:

```
test.cpp: In static member function ‘static void CExample::foo()’:
test.cpp:9: error: invalid use of member ‘CExample::x’ in static member function
```